as.POSIXct renders character cell values to NA
I need to merge two files - both are to have a "Begin Time" column that record time up to milliseconds. I'm having trouble transforming them into compatible DateTime formats and would really appreciate your advice!
df <- read_excel("59387_RPDim_C3.xlsx", sheet = 1)
df2 <- read_excel("74163_RPDim_C4.xlsx", sheet = 1)

Here's what the first two rows of the first two columns look like for 1 file:
~Begin.Time...hh.mm.ss.ms, ~Begin.Time...ss.msec,
"06:18.4",               378.396,
"06:27.0",               386.968
Here's what the first two rows of the first two columns look like for the second file:
~Begin.Time...hh.mm.ss.ms, ~Begin.Time...ss.msec,
"1899-12-31 00:07:07",               426.438,
"1899-12-31 00:07:09",               429.042
When I use the str function:

the first column of the first table lists as "chr"
the first column of the second table lists as "POSIXct[1:213], format: "1899-12-31 00:07:07" "1899-12-31 00:07:09"..." and so on.

Here's one thing I tried to fix this:
df$`Begin Time - hh:mm:ss.ms` <- as.POSIXct(df$`Begin Time - hh:mm:ss.ms`, 
    origin = "1899-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

Here's what happens when I try to transform the first column of the first file into a compatible date format:
~Begin.Time...hh.mm.ss.ms, ~Begin.Time...ss.msec,
NA,               378.396,
NA,               386.968
P.S: This transform code works fine if I apply it to the first column of the second file.
I also tried using the UTC function of the anytime package, to no avail.

I tired to replicate both your data and your error, but I was not able to do so. Hence, perhaps something is different with your data, perhaps the structure or the column/variable names?
Data
Here I tried to replicate your data based on the info you provided:
first_file <- data.frame("V1" = c("06:18.4", "06:27.0"), "V2" = c(378.396, 386.968))
second_file <- data.frame("V1" = c("1899-12-31 00:07:07", "1899-12-31 00:07:09"), "V2" = c(426.438, 429.042 ))

Structure
Here are structure results from this data. Note that in the second dataset I did not find the first column to be in POSIXct-format, but just normal characters.
str(first_file)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "06:18.4" "06:27.0"
 $ V2: num  378 387

str(second_file)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
$ V1: chr  "1899-12-31 00:07:07" "1899-12-31 00:07:09"
$ V2: num  426 429

POSIXct
Lastly, I tried taking the first column of both datasets as POSIXct. Perhaps expectably, the first one does not run due to it's format, while the second one does not generate an error.
as.POSIXct(first_file$V1)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

as.POSIXct(second_file$V1)
[1] "1899-12-31 00:07:07 CET" "1899-12-31 00:07:09 CET"


Thanks so much! When I open these two files in Excel, they have the same format (the first one, and they are not explicitly formatted in Excel in any way). But I do get the unambiguous format error when I try to convert data in the first file. Do you have any advice on what I can do? Since they're the same format on Excel I'm not sure what could help R treat them the same.

No problem! Just wondering; I see you use read_excel() to read in the Excel data, does it make a difference if you use read.xlsx() from the 'xlsx'-package?
Here is a source detailing various ways to read in Excel files: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-excel-files-xls-xlsx-into-r
Perhaps good to see if the issue stems from how the data is read in.
